# How do I avoid repeating type definitions in module declarations?

Tags: flowtype

***Disclaimer:*** I'm still somewhat new Flow and static typing in general, so it's very possible I'm overlooking something easy/obvious with this question.

Say I have a library called `my-library`. The library exposes a single module to its users, `index.js`, which imports a couple other modules (`moduleA.js` and `moduleB.js`) for internal use.

I want to use Flow with this library, both for my own development internally, and in a `index.js.flow` file with a module declaration for users of the library who are also using Flow. So the file structure would look something like this:

```
- index.js
- index.js.flow (contains the module declaration for library users)
- moduleA.js
- moduleA.js.flow (just exported type definitions, no module declaration)
- moduleB.js
- moduleB.js.flow (just exported type definitions, no module declaration)
```

The issue is that the `index.js.flow` module declaration needs to use types from both `moduleA.js.flow` and `moduleB.js.flow`. (The reason I have `moduleA.js.flow` and `moduleB.js.flow` instead of just defining the types directly in the .js files is that the type definitions in the .js files will be stripped out by Babel, and I want them to still exist somewhere for library users).

I know that the following does not type check with external JS that imports `my-module`:

*index.js.flow (this doesn't work)*

```
import type { SomeType } from './moduleA'

declare module 'my-module' {
  declare function exports(): {
    someMethod: () => SomeType
  }
}
```

SomeType doesn't seem to be useable in the module declaration when it's imported, but defining it locally does work:

*index.js.flow (this works)*

```
export type SomeType = string

declare module 'my-module' {
  declare function exports(): {
    someMethod: () => SomeType
  }
}
```

So one solution is to just define and export all types from within `index.js.flow`, and just have `moduleA.js` and `moduleB.js` import them (and not include `.js.flow` files for `moduleA` and `moduleB`), but it seems weird to have all of the type definitions in the root flow file instead of in the `.js.flow` files matching the modules that those types originate from.

Alternatively, I know I could define the types in their respective modules for development, and just define them again in the `index.js.flow` module declaration, but I'd prefer not to have to repeat the type definitions in two different places if possible.

I would greatly appreciate any help figuring out how best to organize this. (And again, I know there's a pretty solid chance I'm doing something dumb or overlooking something obvious.)

Comment: Did you try replacing using `import type ...` instead of `import ...`? So your first attempt would start with `import type { SomeType } from './moduleA'`

Comment: Yes, that is actually what I meant - that was a typo, sorry. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The purpose of `.js.flow` files is to act *exactly* like the corresponding `.js` files in your implementation, *except* that they are not translated by Babel. In particular, they import and export things just like the corresponding `.js` files do. Also, just like a `.js` file is automatically associated with a module based on where it resides in the file system, so is a `.js.flow` file.

Following the example in the question, let's say `index.js`'s `module.exports` is a function that returns an object containing a property `someMethod` of type `() => SomeType`, where the type `SomeType` is exported by `moduleA.js`. Then we can have the following in `index.js.flow`:

```
// @flow

import type { SomeType } from './moduleA'

declare module.exports: () => {
  someMethod: () => SomeType;
};
```

And the following in `moduleA.js.flow`:

```
// @flow

export type SomeType = string;
```

Assuming that we put `index.js.flow` and `moduleA.js.flow` in `src/node_modules/my-module/`, we can test that our setup is correct by having the following in `test.js` in `src/`:

```
// @flow

var foo = require('my-module');

(foo().someMethod(): number); // error (string incompatible with number)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It looks like it was the `declare module 'my-module'` part that was causing the issue. Changing that to simply use `declare module.exports: ...` as you suggested is the only change I had to make to get it to work. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Think of it this way: `.js.flow` is just a replacement for `.js` for typechecking purposes. 

What would `declare module` mean inside a regular `.js` file? That file is *already* defining a module. In this example, `index.js` is already defining the module `my-module` by virtue of being located at `node_modules/my-module`. This is *exactly* what happens with `.js.flow` as well. 

Using `declare module` in a regular `.js` or `.js.flow` file should be an error (it's currently not, but that's a bug). Its use should be limited to "global" declarations pointed to in your `.flowconfig`.